# USB-C (without Thunderbolt) ---> HDMI/DisplayPort - Second external monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, usb-c

I'm planning to buy second monitor, but the only option for me to connect it to my laptop is via USB-C, but I don't have a thunderbolt support. Is it still worth? I mean, I'm not planning gaming(I don't play at all), but as a secondary monitor for work - documentation, video / tutorials (720p/1080p) software, editors etc. Would that work fine? Or I shouldn't bother at all...?

Answer (score 1):

Regular USB can be used to connect to an external graphical card. Typically this is quite slow compared to other methods and I would not recommend it for gaming or 4k displays, but for office applications it works well enough.

I stil use an external cards connected via USB 2 for my low res (1920x1200) display at work.

So:
 1. Yes, no reason why you could not use it.
 2. I am explicitly mentioning USB 2 since I do nto know what kind of USB is connected to your USB-C plug. It is modern form factor and as such you of probably have USB 3 gen 2 on it, but the plug itself does not guarantee anything. USB-1 (only) on a USB-C connector is probably legal.